# Using ScalaTest to test akka actors

Tags: scala, automated-tests, akka, scalatest

I am struggling to find any ScalaTest samples written using FunSuite testing an akka actor.

I appreciate if somebody could provide a simple scalatest example testing a simple akka actor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Akka is very well documented. You can find the documentation [here](http://akka.io/docs/). Here is the link to the [Testing Actor Systems (Scala)](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/scala/testing.html) chapter, which comes with an [example](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/scala/testkit-example.html).

Note: The full example uses a ScalaTest WordSpec. For a FunSuite example, change WordSpec to FunSuite and write tests with test("test name") rather than WordSpec's should/in style. All else will be identical to the example shown.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'm after ScalaTest sample and not Spec sample.

Comment: The linked example *is* in ScalaTest, is it not? I see imports to org.scalatest...

Comment: There is even an explanatory video from Scala Days 2012 http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/scala/actors-fsm-akka.

Answer (score 1):

If you use **FunSuite** you will get an error: "FunSuite needs to be a trait to be mixed in". If you want to use it as in the Akka documentation but replace WordSpec for a FunSuite like test use **FunSuiteLike**. Like this:

```
class ComponentLogicTest() extends TestKit(ActorSystem("ComponentLogicTest")) with ImplicitSender with FunSuiteLike with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterAll {
```